# How to use regex to detect if has any "<", ">" or "%"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is me regex code.

```
/<+>+\%/
```

What i wants to detect any "<", ">", "%" in my string.

Any way can do that?

Comment: `/[<>%]/`...............

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class (brackets)

```
/[<>%]/
```

This is enough to match one.